# FindName returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to get an XAML element with its own name from another C# class, but it's returning always null, why?

Here's the target XAML with its C# class:

```
XAML:
<Page
    x:Class="myApp.SubSpace.SomePage"
    IsTabStop="false"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:myApp.SubSpace"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="target">
    </Grid>
</Page>

C#:
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace myApp.SubSpace 
{
    public sealed partial class SomePage : Page
    {
        public SomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code it's giving me a null result:

```
using myApp.SubSpace;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace myApp.Core
{
    public class Main
    {
        private Grid target;
        public Main() {
            FrameworkElement page = new SomePage();
            this.target = (Grid)page.FindName("target");
        }
    }
}
```

The code is very simplified, but the very important things are there. After calling a new `Main` object, its `target` field is null. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want that for?

Comment: @HighCore As I said, the code is very simplified, but after that the `target` object must be edited.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FindName returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214737/findname-returning-null)

Comment: where you are assigning your XAML to your Class SomePage() ?? I can't see any code in SomePage which involves XAML.

Comment: object must be "edited" - that's what [**DataBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) is for. **It is strongly recommended that you use proper DataBinding in XAML-based technologies as opposed to a traditional, procedural code approach. This is because the Visual Tree is a complex structure and dealing with it becomes too cumbersome.**

Comment: @nvoigt I already visited that post, but it solved nothing to me. In that post the element was generated by code, here I'm trying to retrieve the already defined element from another class in another namespace.

Comment: @HighCore Can't bind the data because i need to edit it by hard coding. I need the element to be very flexible.

Comment: @JordiVilaplana you can do as much flexibility as you need, see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821573/643085) of a dynamic UI done in proper DataBinding.

Comment: XAML's idea of 'dynamic' is very different from other technologies. You need to learn to use `DataTemplates` and other XAML-specific constructs in order to do this. Don't try to force a procedural approach into XAML. It's just not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have a helper static class based on the code snippet in [Tips and Tricks for C# Metro developer: How to find a XAML control by its name](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2012/07/27/tips-and-tricks-for-c-metro-developer-how-to-find-a-xaml-control-by-its-name.aspx). It hasn't let me down yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Grid myGrid= 
this.FindName("target") as Grid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this wasn't the case in the OP's code but I had the same error (null returned from FindChild) and for me it was an issue of calling FindChild in the constructor of a Page before InitializeComponent() was called.  Make sure everything is initialized and ready before looking at the children.