# How to delete dynamically created buttons

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a WPF application in c# and i'm wondering how to delete dynamically created button in grid assuming that i know buttons name.

Explanation: I have 16 buttons and i want to delete two buttons at the same time when i clicked one button. I Have their names but i don't know how to use this.

this is what i tried but this is useful only when you're trying delete clicked button.

```
public void delete(Button x)
{
    myGrid.Children.Remove(x);
}
```

I hope you understand my question because my English is not my native language.

My code:

```
for (int i=1; i<17; i++) 
{
    Button x = new Button();
    x.MinHeight = 100;
    x.MinWidth = 100;
    var brush = new ImageBrush();
    brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:path\slikeSpomin\hrbtnaStran.png", UriKind.Relative));
    x.Background = brush;
    int ime = r.Next(0, max);
    //x.Content = pari[ime];
    x.Name = pari[ime];
    pari.RemoveAt(ime);
    max--;
    x.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    x.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;                
    x.Margin = new Thickness(a, b, 0, 0);
    a = a + 130;
    if (i % 4 == 0)
    {
        b = b + 120;
        a = 10;
    }
    x.Click += new RoutedEventHandler((obj, ev) => btnClick(x));
    gumbiDodani.Insert(0, x);
    gridSlike.Children.Add(x);

} // Here i create my buttons

private void btnClick(Button x)
{
    var brush = new ImageBrush();
    string slika = x.Name;
    sliki.Add(slika);
    brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"path\slikeSpomin\" + slika + ".png", UriKind.Relative));
    x.Background = brush;
    //zaženem metodo, ki preverja enake in se izvede samo v primeru, če so enake
    enake(slika, x);
}
List<string> ksad = new List<string>();
public void enake(string ime, Button x)
{
    ksad.Add(ime);
    if (ksad.Count == 2)
    {
        string prva = ksad[0];
        string druga = ksad[1];
        if (prva.Equals(druga + "a") || druga.Equals(prva + "a"))
        {

            string imeGumba = x.Name;
            MessageBox.Show(prva + "   " + druga);
            //this.gridSlike.Children.re
            gridSlike.Children.Remove(x);
            ksad.Clear();
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("happy");
            ksad.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So your question is how to get a reference to the button if you know its name (a string).

Comment: Post the code here. There might be better solution to your problem.

Comment: how buttons created? post also this code.

Comment: Yes kennyzx but two references because i need to delete two buttons. First reference i get when i clicked on one button and then i remove this button using code i posted in my question. But i need to delete one more button but i don't know how to get reference of it. I only have buttons name

Comment: can't you iterate through the myGrid.children and get button using the name ?

Comment: I don't know i was thinking in that way but i really don't know how to do this

Comment: What's wrong with `myGrid.Children.Remove(NameOfButton);`?

Comment: @Rok check the aswer i have posted it is working for me

Comment: Remove method only takes EIElement for the argument not string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can do something like this lets say the button name is B1

```
 List<Button> remove = new List<Button>();
        foreach (var children in myGrid.Children)
        {
            if ((children.GetType() == typeof(Button)))
            {
                if ((children as Button).Name == "B1")
                    remove.Add(children as Button);
            }
        }
        foreach (var ch in remove)
        {
            myGrid.Children.Remove(ch as Button);
        }
```

or simply

```
myGrid.Children.Remove((UIElement) this.FindName("B1"));
```

like Asfk mentioned in his answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this piece of code:

```
UIElement btn = null;
foreach (Control c in sp.Children)
    if (c.Name == "Button1")
        btn = (UIElement)c;
sp.Children.Remove(btn);
```

Btw, I found the reason why this code `sp.Children.Remove((UIElement)this.FindName("Button0"));` not works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214737/findname-returning-null):

> Any additions to the element tree after initial loading and processing
>   must call the appropriate implementation of RegisterName for the class
>   that defines the XAML namescope. Otherwise, the added object cannot be
>   referenced by name through methods such as FindName. Merely setting a
>   Name property (or x:Name Attribute) does not register that name into
>   any XAML namescope.

Comment: I've tried this but nothing happens. Argument in this method FindName is my buttons name right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of not disposing of it. (Many people are missing that point.) Let's take a code from AsfK's answer:

```
sp.Children.Remove(btn);
```

Try to change it into that:

```
btn.Dispose();
```

(İf the code below doesn't work or gives an error try that: "`sp.Children.btn.Dispose();`")

Hope it helps.