# How to find dynamically created XAML component by Name in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to find dynamically created XAML component by Name in C#?

I created next button and put it into the Stack Panel.

```
var nextButton = new Button();
nextButton.Name = "NextBtn";
next.Children.Add(nextButton);
```

then tried to find it with

```
this.FindName("NextBtn")
```

and it always comes null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Share your xaml code.

Comment: There is not much to share

<StackPanel x:Name="next"></StackPanel>

Comment: possible duplicate of [FindName returning null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214737/findname-returning-null)

Comment: Why don't you match the letter case? You did set name to "NextBtn", large N, but you did called FindName method with parameter "nextBtn", small n. Is there some reason?

Comment: That was not the case.
My mistake was that I was not registering dynamically added components with RegisterName method. After I added this call all become good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Farhad Jabiyev mentioned I created duplicate.

As related question ([FindName returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214737/findname-returning-null)) explaines

from this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx

> Any additions to the element tree after initial loading and processing
>   must call the appropriate implementation of RegisterName for the class
>   that defines the XAML namescope. Otherwise, the added object cannot be
>   referenced by name through methods such as FindName. Merely setting a
>   Name property (or x:Name Attribute) does not register that name into
>   any XAML namescope.

Answer (score 3):

Use `RegisterName` instead of `nextButton.Name = "NextBtn";`

```
var nextButton = new Button();
RegisterName("NextBtn", nextButton); // <-- here
next.Children.Add(nextButton);
```

You can then find it with:

```
this.FindName("NextBtn")
```

Comment: exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

You could find the button manually, for example:

```
foreach (var child in next.Children)
{
    if (child is Button && (child as Button).Name == "NextBtn")
        ;// do what you want with this child
}
```

Or:

```
var btn = next.Children.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(q => q.Name == "NextBtn");
if (btn != null)
    ;// do what you want
```