# How to play and pause MediaElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I want to play MediaElement briefly and then stop it when add listbox items.
It looks like Video Thumbnail. I created a list box dynamically, can I play it back and stop it?

Main.xaml

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AllowDrop="True" Drop="ListBox_Drop" DragEnter="ListBox_DragEnter" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" MouseMove="ListBox_MouseMove">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <MediaElement Margin="3" x:Name="{Binding vName}" Source="{Binding Path}" Height="64" Stretch="Uniform" IsMuted="True"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Main.xaml.cs

```
private void Add_Item(string file)
    {
        extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
        file_name = Path.GetFileName(file);
        if (extension.Equals(".mp4") || extension.Equals(".mwv") || extension.Equals(".avi"))
        {
            list.Add(new VideoListing()
            {
                Name = file_name,
                Path = file,
                vName = file_name,
            });
        }
        listBox.ItemsSource = list;
        listBox.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

VideoListing.cs

```
class VideoListing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string vName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do you want the 'playback' the start? When you add the element to the list? Or afterwards? How should the stop take place? On video end?

Comment: @LupuSilviu When I add to listbox, I want to play it briefly and then stop it. >>Main.xaml.cs>>after "listBox.Items.Refresh();"

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but if you can give each `MediaElement` a unique name, you can probably find it using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393368/how-to-find-dynamically-created-xaml-component-by-name-in-c). Unfortunately I don't use WPF (I mostly do backend dev) so I can't guarantee this will work.

Comment: @John Modified question content. Can you take a look?

Comment: You can set the 'LoadedBehavior' to Play, and that will make the video play as soon as you set the video file. But this will not stop the video briefly. And I cannot see any clean way of doing this. The ugly way would be to BindToSource the MediaElement to the ViewModel, and then you can do anything you want with it.