# WPF: FindName() doesn't work with predefined XAML code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a dynamic layout window app, that by changing the value in a combo box, a value in a text box should change as well.
The text box is part of a grid, that is defined in `<window.resources>` and was added to the visual tree at **run time**:

```
 grpEditFrame.Content = this.Resources["grdARP"] as Grid; // the text box is inside this grid
```

so this is what I did:

```
((grpEditFrame.Content as Grid).
            FindName("txtHardwareType") as TextBox).Text= "some text"
```

Problem is that for some reason `FindName` doesn't find the textbox. By debugging I cant see they exist, but `FindName` just doesn't work :(

So looking up in Google I saw that the problem is that controls that are created at run time, their name are not been registered automatically, so the programmer must do it himself. But then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214737/findname-returning-null?answertab=active#tab-top).

So if a control was created by XAML, like what I did (defined them in `<windows.resources>`)  so what is the problem?

Further more, if I'm not wrong, controls that are in `<windows.resources>` are being created at compile time!

Either why, I think that the names must have been registed, so why can't find them?

This is my `<windows.resources>` definition for the grid above:

```
 <Grid x:Key="grdARP" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="572">
        <Label Content="Destination MAC:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Source MAC:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="199,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Ethernet Type:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="319,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="74,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" MaxLength="12"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="199,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" MaxLength="12"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtEthernetType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="324,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" MaxLength="4"/>
        <Label Content="0x0000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtHardwareType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="429,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" MaxLength="2"/>
        <Label Content="Hardeware type:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="429,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.359,0.5"/>
        <Label Content="Protocol type:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="0x0010" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtProtocolType" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="74,98,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" MaxLength="4"/>
        <Label Content="Hardware size:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtHardwareSize" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="155,98,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78" MaxLength="2"/>
        <Label Content="Protocol size:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="234,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtProtocolSize"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="238,98,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" MaxLength="2"/>
        <Label Content="Opcode:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtOpcode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="316,98,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" MaxLength="4"/>
        <Label Content="Sender MAC:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="366,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="371,98,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" MaxLength="12"/>
        <Label Content="Sender IP:" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="459,72,44,0"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="464,98,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" MaxLength="8"/>
        <Label Content="0x0020" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,157,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Target MAC:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="74,160,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" MaxLength="12"/>
        <Label Content="Target IP:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="181,160,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" MaxLength="8"/>
        <Label Content="RAW: (optional)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="306,134,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="306,160,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="233" MaxLength="12" ToolTip="Any data put here has no effect"/>
        <Label Content="0x0030" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,216,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,216,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Width="465"/>
        <Label Content="RAW : (optional)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  ToolTip="Any data put here has no effect"/>
    </Grid>
```

And this is my C# code behind function:

```
        private void cmdArpHardwareTypes_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //set the hardware type in txtHardwareType text box
        ((grpEditFrame.Content as Grid).
            FindName("txtHardwareType") as TextBox).Text = ((Int16)Enum.Parse(
                                                                              typeof(ArpHardwareTypes),
                                                                              (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString()))

                                                                              .ToString("x4");//4 chars hex format
        //set hardware size to 6 only if harware type is ethernet
        if ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString() == ArpHardwareTypes.Ethernet10MB.ToString())
            ((grpEditFrame.Content as Grid).
            FindName("txtHardwareType") as TextBox).Text = ArpHardwareSize.Ethernet.ToString();

    }
```

### EDIT

`Hoplese` suggested to add UpdateLayout, so this is what I did (and it didn't work...)

```
    void cmbEthernetIItypes_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //clear the editf frame grid
        grpEditFrame.Content = null;
        //clear son of parent (trviEthernetII)
        (trviRoot.Items.GetItemAt(0)/*trivEtherntII*/ as TreeViewItem).Items.Clear();

        switch ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            case "RAW":
                grpEditFrame.Content = this.Resources["grdEthernetIIraw"] as Grid;
                grpEditFrame.UpdateLayout();
                grpEditFrame.InvalidateArrange();
                grpEditFrame.InvalidateMeasure();
                grpEditFrame.InvalidateVisual();
                    break;
            case "ARP":
                //set the edit grpup box
                grpEditFrame.Content = this.Resources["grdARP"] as Grid;
                grpEditFrame.UpdateLayout();
                grpEditFrame.InvalidateArrange();
                grpEditFrame.InvalidateMeasure();
                grpEditFrame.InvalidateVisual();
                //set the tree view item
                (trviRoot.Items.GetItemAt(0)/*trivEtherntII*/ as TreeViewItem).Items.Add(this.Resources["trviARP"]);
                trviRoot.UpdateLayout();
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no NameScope in resources, your controls not a part of logical tree, so you need to call RegisterName, or, and it will be easier in such situation, use VisualTreeHelper

Comment: but how do I register controls that are in resources? and not long ago I used to create dynmic layout with XamlParse() annd I didn't have that problem there. why? there is a NameScope there?

Comment: at the time your code runs, has the `grpEditFrame` had its new Content rendered?

Comment: well, not at the start, but when I click on a combo box, In the code behind, the content is set to be one of the Grids in `<window.resources>`

Comment: I'm not so sure but when it comes to rendering visual tree, you should always call `UpdateLayout` (sometimes can use `InvalidateArrange()`, `InvalidateMeasure`) before actually reading the visual tree (I believe `FindName` would do some visual tree search internally).

Comment: looks like it's stuck to try to make `FindName` work in this case. You can however always use `VisualTreeHelper` to search through the element and filter just the element having the specified `Name`. It surely works that way. `FindName` may just support design time assigned name (in XAML and be initially part of the visual tree). Of course FindName also works against manually registered name at runtime.